# Azure SQL Invalid object name 'sys.server_role_members'

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am getting error "Invalid object name 'sys.server_role_members'"

when running the following query in SQL Server 2014:

```
SELECT sr.name,sp.name 
FROM sys.server_role_members srm
inner join sys.server_principals as sp ON 
srm.member_principal_id = sp.principal_id
inner join sys.server_principals as sr ON
srm.role_principal_id = sr.principal_id
```

I am using Azure SQL and connecting to it via SQL Server 2014 developer version. I checked under system views and I do not see neither sys.server_role_members nor sys.server_principals system views. Does anyone know why those views are not showing up in Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [sys].[database_permissions],[sys].[objects] and [sys].[database_principals] 
instead of sys.server_role_members and sys.server_principals worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Server-level roles and logins are handled a bit differently in Azure SQL Database than they are in SQL Server:

- There two server-level security roles in the master database: loginmanager and dbmanager.
- Instead of sys.server_principals, you use sys.sql_logins in master.

I'd encourage you to take a look at [Managing Databases and Logins in Azure SQL Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336235.aspx) for details on the differences between Azure SQL Database and SQL Server for server-level administration. Note that in most cases, you'll get better performance if you use [contained database users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff929188) with Azure SQL Database, since these users can authenticate directly at the user database and avoid the extra round-trip to master required by logins.

Comment: Thanks. What do I use instead of sys.server_role_member?

Comment: You create both a login and a user for that login in master (see "How to Assign SQL Database Server Roles" in the article above). You can then join sys.database_role_members with sys.database_principals in master to see which principals belong to the loginmanager and dbmanager roles.